# No relationships created after running script

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am following a neo4j Fraud detection example.

It can be found at https://neo4j.com/graphgist/bank-fraud-detection

After I run the script to CREATE nodes and relationships, all without error and everything done, the script in the second part returns nothing.

This creates nodes and relationships

```
Query 1
// Create account holders
CREATE (accountHolder1:AccountHolder {
 FirstName: "John",
 LastName: "Doe",
 UniqueId: "JohnDoe" })

CREATE (accountHolder2:AccountHolder {
 FirstName: "Jane",
 LastName: "Appleseed",
 UniqueId: "JaneAppleseed" })

CREATE (accountHolder3:AccountHolder {
 FirstName: "Matt",
 LastName: "Smith",
 UniqueId: "MattSmith" })

// Create Address
CREATE (address1:Address {
 Street: "123 NW 1st Street",
 City: "San Francisco",
 State: "California",
 ZipCode: "94101" })

// Connect 3 account holders to 1 address
CREATE (accountHolder1)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(address1),
 (accountHolder2)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(address1),
 (accountHolder3)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(address1)

// Create Phone Number
CREATE (phoneNumber1:PhoneNumber { PhoneNumber: "555-555-5555" })

// Connect 2 account holders to 1 phone number
CREATE (accountHolder1)-[:HAS_PHONENUMBER]->(phoneNumber1),
 (accountHolder2)-[:HAS_PHONENUMBER]->(phoneNumber1)

// Create SSN
CREATE (ssn1:SSN { SSN: "241-23-1234" })

// Connect 2 account holders to 1 SSN
CREATE (accountHolder2)-[:HAS_SSN]->(ssn1),
 (accountHolder3)-[:HAS_SSN]->(ssn1)

// Create SSN and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (ssn2:SSN { SSN: "241-23-4567" })<-[:HAS_SSN]-(accountHolder1)

// Create Credit Card and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (creditCard1:CreditCard {
 AccountNumber: "1234567890123456",
 Limit: 5000, Balance: 1442.23,
 ExpirationDate: "01-20",
 SecurityCode: "123" })<-[:HAS_CREDITCARD]-(accountHolder1)

// Create Bank Account and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (bankAccount1:BankAccount {
 AccountNumber: "2345678901234567",
 Balance: 7054.43 })<-[:HAS_BANKACCOUNT]-(accountHolder1)

// Create Credit Card and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (creditCard2:CreditCard {
 AccountNumber: "1234567890123456",
 Limit: 4000, Balance: 2345.56,
 ExpirationDate: "02-20",
 SecurityCode: "456" })<-[:HAS_CREDITCARD]-(accountHolder2)

// Create Bank Account and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (bankAccount2:BankAccount {
 AccountNumber: "3456789012345678",
 Balance: 4231.12 })<-[:HAS_BANKACCOUNT]-(accountHolder2)

// Create Unsecured Loan and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (unsecuredLoan2:UnsecuredLoan {
 AccountNumber: "4567890123456789-0",
 Balance: 9045.53,
 APR: .0541,
 LoanAmount: 12000.00 })<-[:HAS_UNSECUREDLOAN]-(accountHolder2)

// Create Bank Account and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (bankAccount3:BankAccount {
 AccountNumber: "4567890123456789",
 Balance: 12345.45 })<-[:HAS_BANKACCOUNT]-(accountHolder3)

// Create Unsecured Loan and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (unsecuredLoan3:UnsecuredLoan {
 AccountNumber: "5678901234567890-0",
 Balance: 16341.95, APR: .0341,
 LoanAmount: 22000.00 })<-[:HAS_UNSECUREDLOAN]-(accountHolder3)

// Create Phone Number and connect 1 account holder
CREATE (phoneNumber2:PhoneNumber {
 PhoneNumber: "555-555-1234" })<-[:HAS_PHONENUMBER]-(accountHolder3)

RETURN *
```

This is the query against it

```
Query 2
MATCH (accountHolder:AccountHolder)-[]->(contactInformation)
WITH contactInformation,
 count(accountHolder) AS RingSize
MATCH (contactInformation)<-[]-(accountHolder)
WITH collect(accountHolder.UniqueId) AS AccountHolders,
 contactInformation, RingSize
WHERE RingSize > 1
RETURN AccountHolders AS FraudRing,
 labels(contactInformation) AS ContactType,
 RingSize
ORDER BY RingSize DESC
```

any ideas why?

can anyone recreat the problem?

Comment: The second query is returning 3 records here. All working.

Comment: What Neo4j version are you using?

Comment: 3.2.6 community edition

Answer (score 0):

Worked out  whats going on, not sure why though.
I was running the script one command at a time. I have tried running multiple commands at once and I got an error. thats why I was doing it one at a time.

when I ran the full script, it worked. crated all the nodes and their relationships and I was able to query them.

any idea why my original way didnt work?
thanks for your help